# Mock or Simulate HttpResponse with multiple attempts

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'd like to do a JUnit test for a service that could return an HTTP status code (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE). For me, this could be unavailable due to the container being scaled up and not yet reachable. In that case, I'm having the code retry the service up to 3 times.

I can mock an HttpResponse for testing, but only for one situation. Can Mockito create a mocked object that returns one thing on the first attempt, track the number of attempts and return a different result depending on the attempt number? The only thing I can think of doing is to implement my own HttpResponse. Is there a better approach with Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

Stubbing consecutive calls (iterator-style stubbing)

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenReturn("foo");

 //First call: throws runtime exception:
 mock.someMethod("some arg");

 //Second call: prints "foo"
 System.out.println(mock.someMethod("some arg"));

 //Any consecutive call: prints "foo" as well (last stubbing wins).
 System.out.println(mock.someMethod("some arg"));
```